# Split large size csv file into multiple csv files with VS code

Tags: python, csv, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to split over 8GB CSV file into multiple CSV files with VS code?

I tried to split the file based on https://mungingdata.com/python/split-csv-write-chunk-pandas/

```
chunk_size = 2000000

def write_chunk(part, lines):
    with open('split_'+ str(part) +'.csv', 'w') as f_out:
        f_out.write(header)
        f_out.writelines(lines)

with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    count = 0
    header = f.readline()
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        count += 1
        lines.append(line)
        if count % chunk_size == 0:
            write_chunk(count//chunk_size, lines)
            lines = []
    # write remainder
    if len(lines) > 0:
        write_chunk((count//chunk_size) + 1, lines)
```

however, if the filepath set the large CSV file, vscode cannot read the file due to the memory issue.

Although I consider data cleaning in SQL before extracting data as CSV, I wonder how you split the large SCV file.

Comment: How opening CSV file is it related to VS Code? Just run python script from VS Code, don't open CSV yourself

Comment: if you could open it in VSC how would you split it in parts and keep the header, does VSC have a command to do this or are you writing an extension to do it

Comment: Your code doesn't mention a way for `header` to be passed into `write_chunk()`, but otherwise it looks fine. If execution time matters to you, better to ignore the (somewhat slow) python interpreter and follow this bit of advice adapted from the cited webpage: `split --lines=2000000 $FILENAME tmp/split_csv_shell/file` .  Bear in mind that 2 million lines imples quite a few bytes, if you don't have super short lines. Consider tuning that value downward a bit. https://manpages.debian.org/buster/coreutils/split.1.en.html

Comment: VS Code is not a language — it's an Integrated Development Environment ([IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)) — and has little to do with whether Python could split an large CSV file. Running it at the same time as a Python script might reduce the amount of available RAM to some degree, but that would only slow things down because of the need to use virtual memory. To summarize, yes, it's possible.

Comment: I had executed the code in VS Code, but the file was split by changing PyCharm with the same code. Finally, the original file was converted into 198 files within a few minutes.